# How do I specify a range of spaces in perl script?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have two files namely `abc_0123_4567.dat` created on *Aug 3* and `abc_0012_0043.dat` created on *Aug 14*.

when we type `ls -ltra` into the shell, we get

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user  sample   640578  Aug  3  03:15  abc_0123_4567.dat
-rw-r--r--   1 user  sample   488542  Aug 14  03:20  abc_0012_0043.dat
```

When we use `ls -ltra abc* | grep "Aug  3"`
it will display

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user  sample   640578  Aug  3  03:15  abc_0123_4567.dat
```

You can see in date, `Aug  3` has two spaces in between and `Aug 14` has one space in between.

I want to see the same result when coded in perl taking exact spaces as with the shell command.

Comment: Try: `/  ?/` See `perldoc perlre` for details.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. It is a bad idea to shell out to `ls` to get a list of files and then `grep` the list in Perl. What problem is this approach supposed to solve? I am certain a short program using `File::Find` will do the job

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get the Aug  3 files in perl script. I had shown example of hoe to get it in unix shell. I just want to get the file using perl script.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking is for a regex that takes both the one-digit and the two-digit cases.

First of all if you don't actually care about number of spaces, you could do this:

```
qr/ ( \b        # At word boundary
      (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Ju[ln]|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) # 3-letter months
      [ ]{1,2}   # minumum 1, maximum 2 spaces
      \d{1,2}    # minumum 1, maximum 2 digits
    )
   /x;
```

But this allows `'Aug..14'` (where `'.'` -> `' '`), if that should ever happen.

Second, if you want a tighter specification, you could do the following

```
qr/ ( \b        # At word boundary
      (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Ju[ln]|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) # 3-letter months
      [ ]       # exactly one space
      [ 123]    # it's a *date* after all
      \d        # ending with a digit
    )
   /;
```

Thus you get a three-character sequence, one definite space, one space or possible number equal or less than 3, and one definite digit of any size.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the modification dates of a bunch of files, you'd be way better off using the mtime returned by the stat operator than parsing the output of ls.

It'll be a number that you can use the localtime() operator on to break it into date fields.

Parsing ls output is almost never the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions always match exact spaces:

```
ls -ltra abc* | perl -nE "print if /Aug  3/"
```

is pretty much identical to:

```
ls -ltra abc* | grep "Aug  3"
```

Comment: The "re" in grep is for "regular expression", by the way. It uses a slightly different flavor of regular expressions than Perl, but the syntax means exactly the same thing in both cases for this particular example. (Match "A", then match "u", then match "g", then match " ", then match " ", then match "3". Return any line matching that sequence.)

Comment: The above example requires the `-n` switch to iterate over all input lines. The present code wouldn't even read any data from STDIN! (`| perl -ne 'print if /Aug  3/'` would work)